# Java Logger - Configuration changes not reflected on runtime

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I have 2 configuration files for logging,
config1.properties and
config2.properties

When I load the config1.properties and log something, the format is correct, but right after, when I load the second config file, the changes are not reflected. Here is my code:

```
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "config1.properties");
logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
logger.info("Message 1");
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "config2.properties");
LogManager logManager = LogManager.getLogManager();
logManager.readConfiguration();
logger = Logger.getLogger("NewLogger");
logger.info("Message 2");
```

I have set the configuration in config2.properties to log messages in 2 lines, however the message is still showing in one line.

Any ideas why the new configuration is not taking effect? I am sure that my config files are correct, because I tried loading config2 before config1, and that showed my logged messages in 2 lines.

Here is the logged result:

```
[01-13-2014 16:48:56:186] LoggerUnitTest INFO: Message 1
[01-13-2014 16:48:56:195] LoggerUnitTest INFO: Message 2
```

It should show up as :

```
[01-13-2014 16:48:56:186] LoggerUnitTest INFO: Message 1
[01-13-2014 16:48:56:195] LoggerUnitTest INFO:
```

Message 2

Below are the config files I am using:

`config1.properties`

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level= FINE

# Limit the message that are printed on the console to INFO and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter.format = [%1$tm-%1$td-%1$tY %1$tk:%1$tM:%1$tS:%1$tL] %4$s: %5$s%6$s%n
```

`config2.properties`

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level= FINE

# Limit the message that are printed on the console to INFO and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
# Note that this line is different from the line in config1
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter.format = [%1$tm-%1$td-%1$tY %1$tk:%1$tM:%1$tS:%1$tL] %n %4$s: %5$s%6$s%n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

Test.java

```
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "config1.properties");
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getSimpleName());
    logger.info("Message 1");
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "config2.properties");
    LogManager logManager = LogManager.getLogManager();
    logManager.readConfiguration();
    logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getSimpleName());
    logger.info("Message 2");
  }
}
```

config1.properties

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level= FINE

# Limit the message that are printed on the console to INFO and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

config2.properties

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level= FINE

# Limit the message that are printed on the console to INFO and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
```

javac Test.java
java Test

```
Jan 13, 2014 8:51:20 PM Test main
INFO: Message 1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
<record>
  <date>2014-01-13T20:51:20</date>
  <millis>1389664280170</millis>
  <sequence>1</sequence>
  <logger>Test</logger>
  <level>INFO</level>
  <class>Test</class>
  <method>main</method>
  <thread>10</thread>
  <message>Message 2</message>
</record>
```

Comment: Please check my original answer, I have proposed a different config file for you to try, can you help me figure out why the formatter.format property is not getting updated?

Comment: I didn't do much differently from you. How about you try to create the logger the same way each time? In your case: Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getSimpleName());

Comment: Ok, well that's not it.. are you able to see that my example works? It should have all that you need. I'd start with the example that works and try to change it into what you are after. What I gave is quite minimal, so should be straightforward.

Comment: I have started with your example, and it works perfect, but as soon as I try to change formatter.format property, it does not work, please check my original answer for the properties files that I have modified from your answer. Can you confirm if that exact one works?

Comment: I was using Java6 for this. Looked to me like you were using a feature of Java7 where you could set the format string in the logger config xml. One thing I noticed was that the examples I found elsewhere (e.g.,  http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/river/jtsk/skunk/surrogate/testfiles/logging.properties) the pattern seemed to be to set the format on the SimpleLoggingFormatter rather than as you did on the ConsoleHandler.formatter--so maybe something to check there. I would suggest you fall back to use the Java API to play with getting the format differences as you like rather than XML config.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Documentation of the `Logger.getLogger(String name)`.[documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLogger%28java.lang.String%29)

it says

> If a new logger is created its log level will be configured based on
>   the LogManager configuration and it will configured to also send
>   logging output to its parent's handlers. It will be registered in the
>   LogManager global namespace.

So Even though set a new configuration properties your logger instance have the old configuration

try getting a new instance by calling following line again

```
logger = Logger.getLogger("new Name");
```

may be you might have to change the input parameter name differently. or it will return the old logger object

**EDIT**

Here the sample code i tried

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoggingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "config1.properties");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingTest.class.getSimpleName());
        logger.info("Message 1");
        System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "config2.properties");
        LogManager logManager = LogManager.getLogManager();
        try {
            logManager.readConfiguration();//logManager.readConfiguration(new FileInputStream(new File("config2.properties")));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoggingTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoggingTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        logger = Logger.getLogger("NewLogger");
        logger.info("Message 2");

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this, same result. Please check my new code above, I have added the changes

Comment: @ShehryarFarooq, you should add it after you read the configuration, put it after logManager.readConfiguration();

Comment: @ShehryarFarooq, instead of logManger.readConfiguration(); replace it with logManager.readConfiguration(new FileInputStream(new File("config2.properties")));

Comment: I have tried that before asking the question, I will try it again

Comment: Tried that, same result :( , the second logged message is not showing up the way I have configured it (show up in 2 lines)

Comment: @ShehryarFarooq, you mean now first log message not showing properly?

Comment: The first message, "Message 1" shows up the way I want it to, as configured in config1.properties, but the second message "Message 2", does not show up the way it is configured to show up in config2.properties, so the problem is still not resolved after your suggestions :(

Comment: @ShehryarFarooq, it's working for me, i have written a sample program first to output using SimpleFormatter and second to output XMLFormatter and it works.

Comment: Can I see the sample code? The only thing I am changing in my second config2.properties file is the   java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format property, however it is not reflecting the change

Comment: I see the sample code, can you do me a favor and set both of config files to use a simple formatter? But just change the format of the simple format, so that the first one prints out the message in one line, and the second one prints out the message in two lines, I have it like so: java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = [%1$tm-%1$td-%1$tY %1$tk:%1$tM:%1$tS:%1$tL] %2$s %4$s: %5$s%6$s%n     in config1 , and   java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = [%1$tm-%1$td-%1$tY %1$tk:%1$tM:%1$tS:%1$tL] %2$s %n %4$s: %5$s%6$s%n   in config2

Comment: As you can see, I am just adding "%n" to the format in config2, so that it shows up in two lines

Comment: I have myself just tried changing the type of formatter in the config2.properties file to an XMLFormatter, and it WORKS, I see that the second message now shows up in XMLFormatter, this is proof that the file is getting loaded, but still the SimpleFormatter.format property is not getting updated

Comment: @ShehryarFarooq, try adding following line before assigning the logger object for the second time, System.setProperty(""java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", "[%1$tm-%1$td-%1$tY %1$tk:%1$tM:%1$tS:%1$tL] %2$s %n %4$s: %5$s%6$s%n"); I'm using java 1.6 so i need to run java 1.7 to test your scenario

Comment: Tried that, still not working, I think the formatter property is not getting overwritten, or even the SimpleFormatter object :(

Comment: @ShehryarFarooq, I looked at the source file of the SimpleFormatter. 'fomat' field is static final, that means once initialize you cannot change it. Unfortunately it is my understanding that you don't have a way of solving your problem